# spring-cloud-stream and kafka-clients backward compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have a micro services that currently uses `spring-cloud-stream` Ditmars.RELEASE that in turn uses `kafka-clients` 0.10.1.1. 
We are interested in upgrading to `spring-cloud-stream` 2.0.0.RC3 that in turn uses `kafka-clients` 1.0.0 in order to maybe solve a problem that we have: [Kafka messages are reprocessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111565/kafka-messages-are-reprocessed). 
After we upgraded **only one** of our services to `spring-boot` 2.0.0.RELEASE and  `spring-cloud-stream` 2.0.0.RC3 we encountered strange behavior:

The service that was upgraded (from now I will call it service-1) is a producer of a certain topic `send-enrollment-mail`. Also, we have another (service-2), that uses the older versions of `spring-cloud-stream` and `kafka-clients`, and that is a consumer of this topic. When we are booting service-1 it creates this topic with the appropriate partitions, then we are booting service-2 (that uses the with the new versions) and finally produce a message from service-1 we are receiving the following exception

```
 org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:406) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:725) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RC3.jar:2.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.producer.MessageProducer.send(MessageProducer.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.service.EnrollmentServiceImpl.sendEnrollmentMail(EnrollmentServiceImpl.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.service.EnrollmentServiceImpl.enrollUsers(EnrollmentServiceImpl.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.handler.UsersEnrollmentMessageHandler.handleMessage(UsersEnrollmentMessageHandler.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.handler.UsersEnrollmentMessageHandler.handleMessage(UsersEnrollmentMessageHandler.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.consumer.MessageConsumer.lambda$handleMessageWithRetry$0(MessageConsumer.java:84) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.consumer.MessageConsumer.handleMessageWithRetry(MessageConsumer.java:77) [classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.consumer.MessageConsumer.handleUsersEnrollmentMessage(MessageConsumer.java:65) [classes/:na]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.consumer.MessageConsumer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8b03a437.invoke() [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) [spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:112) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) [spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) [spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.watercorp.app.messaging.consumer.MessageConsumer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3ae110f.handleUsersEnrollmentMessage() [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RC3.jar:2.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:87) [spring-cloud-stream-2.0.0.RC3.jar:2.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108) [spring-messaging-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203) [spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:70) [spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:387) [spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:364) [spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1001) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:981) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:932) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:801) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:689) [spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:133) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.processSendResult(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:507) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:398) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate$1.onCompletion(KafkaTemplate.java:354) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:596) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:557) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:481) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:692) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request
```

And also the following error is printed:

```
ERROR 22159 --- [ad | producer-5] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{123, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 69, 78, 82, 79, 76, 76, 7...' to topic send-enrollment-mail and partition 7:
```

**Some notes:** 
1. The message get sent to kafka server and stored there - when I open a console consumer for this topic I see the message that was  by service-1 sent. 
2. The message is not consumed by the service-2 that subscribed to this topic. 
3. After some time service-2 starts spitting the following errors every millisecond

```
WARN 11837 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition send-enrollment-mail-5
```

4. When I stop service-2 and then produce another message from service-1, service-1 not receiving the UnknownServerException error. 
5. Then when I start service-2 it spitting the

```
WARN 11837 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition send-enrollment-mail-5
```

for each partition that has at least one message that was sent from the producer.

I would appreciate any help with this issue

Comment: I think you have a Client-Broker incompatibility. Try to play with different versions combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `headerMode=embeddedHeaders` or `none` for compatibility with older (Ditmars) SCSt apps (depending on which header more those apps use). The native header mode for 2.0 apps is `native` - since Kafka now supports headers.

Comment: @GarryRussell I have another problem now when trying to consume a message with the upgraded service (service-1). The message cannot be converted and it seems that the reason is that the contentType headers of the message that was sent are `contentType=text/plain`, `originalContentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8`. Although the producer configuration have `spring.cloud.stream.default.contentType=application/json`.How do I solve this issue? Preferably without changing the producers (we have multiple services with the old versions of SCS).

Comment: You need to ask a new question, including much more detail - producer/consumer configuration, @StreamListener etc, and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @GarryRussell I asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49409104/spring-cloud-stream-message-conversion-exception