# spring-cloud-stream message conversion exception

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

While upgrading one of our services to `spring-cloud-stream` 2.0.0.RC3 we encountered an exception when trying to consume a message that was produced by a service that uses older version of `spring-cloud-stream` - Ditmars.RELEASE:

> ERROR 31241 --- [container-4-C-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [com.watercorp.messaging.types.incoming.UsersDeletedMessage] for GenericMessage [payload=byte[371], headers={kafka_offset=1, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@62029d0d, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, message_id=1645508761, id=f4e947de-22e6-b629-229b-4fa961c73f2d, type=USERS_DELETED, kafka_receivedPartitionId=4, contentType=text/plain, kafka_receivedTopic=user, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1521641760698, timestamp=1521641772477}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[371], headers={kafka_offset=1, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@62029d0d, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, message_id=1645508761, id=f4e947de-22e6-b629-229b-4fa961c73f2d, type=USERS_DELETED, kafka_receivedPartitionId=4, contentType=text/plain, kafka_receivedTopic=user, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1521641760698, timestamp=1521641772477}]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:164)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
>       at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:463)
>       at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:407)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
>       at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:70)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:387)
>       at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:364)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1001)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:981)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:801)
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:689)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

It looks like that the cause is that the `contentType` header that is sent with the message is `text/plain` although it should be `application/json`. 
The producer configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            brokers: kafka
            defaultBrokerPort: 9092
            zkNodes: zookeeper
            defaultZkPort: 2181
            minPartitionCount: 2
            replicationFactor: 1
            autoCreateTopics: true
            autoAddPartitions: true
            headers: type,message_id
            requiredAcks: 1
            configuration:
              "[security.protocol]": PLAINTEXT #TODO: This is a workaround. Should be security.protocol
          bindings:
            user-output:
              producer:
                sync: true
                configuration:
                  retries: 10000
        default:
          binder: kafka
          contentType: application/json
          group: user-service
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
          producer:
            partitionKeyExtractorClass: com.watercorp.user_service.messaging.PartitionKeyExtractor
        bindings:
          user-output:
            destination: user
            producer:
              partitionCount: 5
```

Consumer configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            brokers: kafka
            defaultBrokerPort: 9092
            minPartitionCount: 2
            replicationFactor: 1
            autoCreateTopics: true
            autoAddPartitions: true
            headers: type,message_id
            requiredAcks: 1
            configuration:
              "[security.protocol]": PLAINTEXT #TODO: This is a workaround. Should be security.protocol
          bindings:
            user-input:
              consumer:
                autoRebalanceEnabled: true
                autoCommitOnError: true
                enableDlq: true            
        default:
          binder: kafka
          contentType: application/json
          group: enrollment-service
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
            headerMode: embeddedHeaders
          producer:
            partitionKeyExtractorClass: com.watercorp.messaging.PartitionKeyExtractor
            headerMode: embeddedHeaders
        bindings:          
          user-input:
            destination: user
            consumer:
              concurrency: 5
              partitioned: true
```

Consumer @StreamListener:

```
    @StreamListener(target = UserInput.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='" + USERS_DELETED + "'")
    public void handleUsersDeletedMessage(@Valid UsersDeletedMessage usersDeletedMessage, @Header(value = "kafka_receivedPartitionId",
            required = false) String partitionId, @Header(value = KAFKA_TOPIC_HEADER_NAME, required = false) String topic, @Header(MESSAGE_ID_HEADER_NAME) String messageId) throws Throwable {
        logger.info(String.format("Received users deleted message message, message id: %s topic: %s partition: %s", messageId, topic, partitionId));
        handleMessageWithRetry(_usersDeletedMessageHandler, usersDeletedMessage, messageId, topic);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in RC3; [recently fixed on master](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/a972cdeabab3a25a51aeb8e35989a05c26a9f1aa); it will be in the GA release due at the end of the month. In the meantime, can you try with 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT?

I was able to reproduce the problem and using the snapshot fixed it for me...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT**

For completeness:

Ditmars producer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So49409104Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49409104Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setBar("bar");
            output.send(new GenericMessage<>(foo));
        };
    }


    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: so49409104a
          content-type: application/json
          producer:
            header-mode: embeddedHeaders
```

Elmhurst consumer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So494091041Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So494091041Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String bar;

        public String getBar() {
            return this.bar;
        }

        public void setBar(String bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [bar=" + this.bar + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: so49409104
          destination: so49409104a
          consumer:
            header-mode: embeddedHeaders
          content-type: application/json
```

Result:

```
Foo [bar=bar]
```

The `header-mode` is required since the default in 2.0 is `native` now that Kafka supports headers natively.

Comment: Using  Elmhurst.BUILD-SNAPSHOT fixed it. Thanks again!